# async method declaration without `function` keyword in side javascript class

Tags: javascript, async-await

Recently I've seen some code example with javascript class, when declaring an async method, it does not contain the `function` keyword, nor it's using an arrow function as usual, code example

```
export default class CartClient {
   async getCart(authToken, cartId) {
    const request = this.request
      .url(`${this.url}/${cartId}`)
      .get()
      .auth(authToken)
      .withNoCache()
      .build();
    const response = await fetch(request);

    return await response.json();
  }
}
```

This is the very first time I've seen things like this, usually I was told to create function using `function` keyword or arrow function like below

```
async function getCart() {
   // implementation
}
or
async getCart = () => {
   // implementation
}
```

Could anyone let me know why we don't need the `function` keyword anymore when declaring the method? Is it a javascript related feature or react feature? Since I've seen in a react project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods in classes do not have the `function` prefix. In fact, they are disallowed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: ah yeah! I was stupid...I've been creating methods in class without `async` before and somehow didn't recognize it...